# Односвязный список, приведение подобных слагаемых

Tags: c++, linked-list

Есть такой код для приведения подобных слагаемых многочлена, представленным однонаправленным списком, от одной переменной.

```
poly *removeDuplicates (poly *start) { 
    poly *ptr = start, *dup;
    // если 1  или 2 элемента
    if (ptr -> next == NULL)
        return start; 
    if (ptr -> next -> next == NULL) {
        if (ptr -> power == ptr -> next -> power) {
            ptr -> coeff = ptr -> coeff + ptr -> next -> coeff;
            dup = ptr -> next;
            ptr -> next = NULL;
            delete (dup);
        }
        return start;
    }
    // если больше
    while (ptr -> next != NULL && ptr != NULL) {
        if (ptr -> power == ptr -> next -> power) {
            ptr -> coeff = ptr -> coeff + ptr -> next -> coeff;
            dup = ptr -> next;
            if (ptr -> next -> next == NULL) {
                ptr -> next = NULL;
            } else {
                ptr -> next = ptr -> next -> next;
            }
            cout << 1;
            delete (dup);
        }
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Многочлен поступает в функцию уже отсортированным, и соответственно я проверяю два соседних элемента списка на равенство их степеней (power - степень элемента списка, coeff - его коэффициент). Если они равны, то в первом из элементов я меняю коэффициент, а второй удаляю из списка.

Моя проблема в том, что программа не выходит из последнего цикла while. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, конечно, не эксперт, но мб стоит поставить условие while (ptr != NULL)?